# How to implement JSF button with image and button label

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I want to implement JSF button with image and custom label. I tested this code:

```
<h:commandButton id="savesettings" styleClass="avesettings" value=" Save Settings " action="#{GeneralController.updateDBSettings}" rendered="true" update="growl">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>

.avesettings {
    background-image: url('../images/small.png');
}
```

This is the result:

[image]

I also tested this second code:

```
<h:commandButton id="savesettings" image="resources/images/first.png" value=" Save Settings " action="#{GeneralController.updateDBSettings}" rendered="true" update="growl">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

I get this result with no label:

[image]

Can you help me to create JSF button with background image and custom label defined as button attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following JSF/CSS should solve your problem:

JSF (the same as in your first example):

```
<h:commandButton id="savesettings" styleClass="avesettings" value="Save Settings" action="#{GeneralController.updateDBSettings}" rendered="true" update="growl">
    <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"></f:ajax>
</h:commandButton>
```

CSS (adapted):

```
.avesettings {
    background: url('../images/small.png') no-repeat;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 126px;
    height: 41px;
    border: none;
}
```

Width and height of the css must be the width and height of your image. I also have the css in an external css file, not direct in the JSF template.

Comment: You should still load small.png as a resource - i.e. url(#{resource['images/small.png']}). Then include the css as a resource - i.e. <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="buttons.css" />

Comment: How can we add bootstrap image (glyph icon)?

Answer (score 2):

The first method that you have used `styleClass="avesettings"` i.e., using CSS style is the only possible way to do it since if you specify the image attribute, the input element will become an image.

See also [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/commandButton.html)

So your best bet would be to use advanced styling techniques for the buttons, refer to these articles for that:

- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2009/11/18/designing-css-buttons-techniques-and-resources/
- http://www.tyssendesign.com.au/articles/css/styling-form-buttons/

Comment: Would you please show me how the source code must be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the ["image" attribute](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/commandButton.jsf?tab=info&cid=1060125) of he commandButton tag?

Comment: Yes, the second example uses `image` attribute. But it's not working as I want - there is no label on the button - just empty button.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice. Can you check with firebug if the imagen has been applied?

Comment: Yes this is the output HTML code: `<input id="settingsupdate:savesettings" type="image" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'action','@form','@form');return false" name="settingsupdate:savesettings" src="resources/images/first.png">` and the visual result is the second picture from the post with no label.

Comment: I think the code is correct. Can you check in the firebug "Net" tab that you arent receiving a 403/404 for your image?

Comment: I get the image correctly. There is no error into the Net tab.

Answer (score 1):

One way to implement this is to load the image as jsf resource in your style sheet:

```
    <style type="text/css">
        .imageButton
        {
            background-image:url(#{resource['images/button.png']});
        }
    </style>
```

Then set the relevant commandButton styleClass in the xhtml:

```
    <h:commandButton value="Submit" styleClass="imageButton" action="#{...}"/>
```

Put the file button.png under your resources folder i.e. resources/images/button.png and make sure your resources folder is located next to your WEB-INF folder

Or if you want the image to display as an icon next to the text in the commandButton then you can play around with css a little:

```
        .imageButton
        {
            padding: ...
            border: ...
            color: ...
            background: [<'background-color'> || <'background-image'> || <'background-repeat'> || <'background-attachment'> || <'background-position'>] 
        }
```